# In Angular2, How can I transfer data between two components. (They are siblings)

Tags: angular

I know the way to transfer data between child and parent components.

Now,I want to transfer data from one component to another one. These two components are sibling.They have the same parent component.

I'm new with angular2. help.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Please post the code. What data do you transfer between what components at what time?

Comment: you can use `@input` and `@output`.

Comment: Please share what you have done

Comment: Sorry, it's too many code to delete and paste. Anyway,thank you.

Comment: I'm new here to learn program and English. I'll share more info in next question. THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transfer data (share data) using service. Create one service where one component can send data to service and other component can receive data.

### Here is an example

#### SharedService.ts

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

export class SharedService {

    public data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    shareData(data: any) {
        this.data$.next(data);
    }
}
```

#### first.component.ts (Send data)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedService } from './SharedService.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'first',
  templateUrl: './first.html'
})
export class firstCompoenent {
    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

    shareData(data) {
        this.sharedService.shareData(data);
    }
}
```

#### second.component.ts (Receive data)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedService } from './SharedService.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'second',
  templateUrl: './second.html'
})
export class secondCompoenent {
    sharedData: any

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
        this.sharedService.data$.subscribe(data => this.sharedData = data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You got solution or still any problem in this example.